Azure Devops Pipeline: Cannot set subscription dynamically
I have the following pipeline, based on this questions answer;
parameters:
  - name: stages
    type: object
    default:
      - stage: sandbox
        variableGroup: ApiLinter-terraform-variables-sandbox

stages:
  - ${{ each stage in parameters.stages }} :
      - stage: Deploy${{ stage.stage }}
        displayName: Deploy ${{ stage.stage }} Environment
        dependsOn: ${{ stage.dependsOn }}
        variables:
          - group: ${{ stage.variableGroup }}
        jobs:
          - job:
            displayName: "${{ stage.stage }}"
            steps:
              - task: Bash@3
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: 'env | sort'
              - task: Bash@3
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: 'echo "ENVIRONMENTSERVICENAMEAZURERM: $(ENVIRONMENTSERVICENAMEAZURERM)"'
              - task: AzureCLI@2
                displayName: Fetch credentials for azure
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: '$(ENVIRONMENTSERVICENAMEAZURERM)'
                  scriptType: bash
                  addSpnToEnvironment: true # this will add the required credentials to env vars
                  useGlobalConfig: true
                  scriptLocation: inlineScript
                  inlineScript: |
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID;]$tenantId"
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID;]$servicePrincipalId"
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;]$servicePrincipalKey"

The issue is, when I remove/comment out the AzureCLI@2 task, the Bash script shows that the variable ENVIRONMENTSERVICENAMEAZURERM has a valid value:

But when I include the AzureCLI2 task I get the following error:
There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job Job1: Step AzureCLI input connectedServiceNameARM references service connection $(ENVIRONMENTSERVICENAMEAZURERM) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist, has been disabled or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."
I'm 100% sure the authorization is set just fine, because when I hardcode the value it works fine. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Where and when is ENVIRONMENTSERVICENAMEAZURERM being defined? If it's a compile-time variable, try using compile-time syntax, ${{ variables.ENVIRONMENTSERVICENAMEAZURERM }}.

The azureSubscription in AzureCLI@2 is evaluated at compile time, the value should be already known(predefined or hardcode) at complile time, it's not supported to dynamically define it in pipeline.
Neither $(var) or ${{ variables.var }} syntax will work if you dynamically link variable group for each stage.
You need to define the variable, or link variable group explicitly ahead in yaml:

Define the subscription variable ahead in yaml:

variables:
  - name: ENVIRONMENTSERVICENAMEAZURERM
    value: ARMConn2


Or define the variable group ahead in yaml:

variables:
- group: ApiLinter-terraform-variables-sandbox

Then azureSubscription: '$(ENVIRONMENTSERVICENAMEAZURERM)' in AzureCLI@2 can be evaluated.

Please check the similar tickets here and here for your reference.
I fully understand your concern, if you'd like the feature, it's recommended to raise a user voice ticket on Community link here, thanks.

thank you so much!! Setting the variable as you shown in both options works. Even though I then first set it to the variables for the sandbox environment, when it gets to the 'test' stage it loads the correct values from the test variable group.
